# Mac GameCenter for mac not working with sandboxing

Tags: macos, xcode4, game-center, review, sandbox

Mac

Mac OS X 10.8.2  /  XCode 4.5.2  / Mac Pro

I have 3 times rejected from apple review.
Help me~ please

DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM

I have problem GameCenter for mac.

```
Xcode -> sandboxing enable .   GameCenter don't work

Xcode -> sandboxing disable.   GameCenter work
```

What to do?  How to work GameCenter with sandboxing?

Error message below.

```
"CONNECTION INVALID"
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099"
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your entitlements to fix this:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.game-center</key>
<true/>
```

It's strange that Xcode doesn't provide this as an entitlement option, but your app will be rejected during the review process if you don't include this.

Comment: Just encountered the same problem.
Adding line makes things even worse, game refuses to start writing "Terminated due to codesigning issues"